# Rails: a singular resource nested on the index of another resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have an User(plural) and a Subscription(singular) controllers. I am wondering if I can set a route like the following:

```
/users/subscription/edit
```

which means editing the subscription of the current user. All examples I see are like `/users/1/subscription/edit`

This way any user can point to this same url and it will direct to their settings page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the routes like :

```
match '/users/subscription/edit' => 'subscription#edit' : as => "subscription_edit"
OR
match '/users/subscription/edit', :controller => 'subscription', :action => 'edit' : as => "subscription_edit"
```